# How to get full screen bounds with correct orientation?

Tags: objective-c, orientation, bounds, cgrect

guys.
I have such problem: I need to use full screen for my view. So I use

```
[_activityIndicator setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

It's work perfect, but only in portrait view. What to do if my app have to work in landscape too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app has a root view controller, which rotates in response to device rotation. So set your frame in terms of the root view controller's view. Use its *bounds*, not its frame.

You can get a reference to the root view controller through the main window. You can get a reference to the main window through the shared application:

```
UIWindow* theWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIViewController* rvc = theWindow.rootViewController;
UIView* mainView = rvc.view;
UIActivityIndicatorView* act = 
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: mainView.bounds];
[mainView addSubview: act];
```

And then you retain a reference to the activity indicator in a property and set it spinning.

Comment: Works nice! Thanks!
`[_activityIndicator setFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view.bounds];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view addSubview:_activityIndicator];`

Comment: Perfect answer, but sorry I can't give +1 to you. Reputation == 8 :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the checkmark! If you're just getting started, there's an online free version of my book. To learn about frame and bounds: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame To learn about view controllers and rotation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation

Answer (score 1):

To get current screen bounds i use:

```
CGRect screenBoundsDependOnOrientation()
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds ;
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds)  ;
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds) ;
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
        screenBounds.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
        screenBounds.size = CGSizeMake(height, width);
    }
    return screenBounds ;
}
```